# how to write the output to .m file using matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have written a matlab code for finding conditional entropy of few datasamples. I am able to get the result in command window. But i want it store in a file(matlab file). I have searched for it got to know that dairy() is used to do that . But as i am new to matlab i am unable to understand it. Please somebody guide me to save my output in a .m file

```
function [ count ] = csvrd()

[num,txt,raw] = xlsread('1500samplesdata.xlsx');
[C1, ia, ic] = unique(raw(:,1),'rows');
[C2, ia, ic] = unique(raw(:,2),'rows');
[C3, ia, ic] = unique(num(:,1),'rows');

sz=size(C1,1);
C1
C2
C3
count=zeros(size(C1,1),size(C2,1));
for k=1:size(raw,1)
for i=1:sz
ss(i)=0;
if(strcmp(raw(k,1),C1(i)))

for j=1:size(C2,1)
    if(strcmp(raw(k,2),C2(j)))

       %  for g=1:size(C3,1)
    %if(num(k,1)==C3(g))

    count(i,j)=count(i,j)+1;
    %end;
     %    end;
end
end
end

end
end
count
end
```

command used to get the result is

```
xxyy=csvrd();
```

Comment: do you mean save to mat file?  save would be a good choice http://www.mathworks.cn/cn/help/matlab/ref/save.html

Answer (score 0):

If memory from college serves me, you don't save output to .m files.  They are like script files. They contain the instructions to get the outputs you want but not the outputs themselves.
The diary function you are referring to is what it sounds like it's a diary of what you do, so it records any input you give it & then the output it gives you back, kind of like a log.
You can save variables to an output file using the "save" command.  If you just run the save command in your script it will save the current variables to a .mat file which is matlab's output file type. It will save it to your working folder.  You can run a function to create the filename dynamically with a timestamp or something if need be to run it multiple times without overwriting.  But "save" is what you want not "diary".

```
save condentr.mat
```

Answer (score 0):

`.m` files are for storing MATLAB code and `.mat` files are for storing data.  You can save a particular set of variables in a `.mat` file by using the `save` command:

```
a = 5;
b = 'some text';
save myfile.mat a b
```

See the [Save workspace variables to file](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) document for details.

You can then load the data back using the `load` command:

```
clear  % will clear all variables in the workspace
whos   % confirm that there are no variables
load myfile.mat
whos   % confirm that variables are loaded back.
```